# Display image in Java JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, image

What's the best way to display an image at specific coordinates in a java JFrame?

I know there are a number of ways to do this, I just need to know the best way to display an image that I am planning on moving around the frame!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding it as an ImageIcon:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("image.jpeg");
add(image);
```

---

EDIT (How to add it add specific coordinates):

*First a note, usually (99% of the cases) it is NOT encouraged to position JComponents yourself. Use a LayoutManager to position them for you, and handle the resizing.*
I will tell you how to position it yourself though:

- Set your LayoutManager to `null`: `setLayout(null)`.
- set your `ImageIcon` to specific coordinates: `image.setLocation(x, y)`.

Comment: Thanks! I really like this idea, it's simple and makes sense.
Although how would one-such as myself-display this picture at specific coordinates?

Comment: Thanks,
Just out of curiosity though, if I wanted to position the image at specified coordinates, what do you think the best way of doing it would be?

Comment: I gave instructions in the edit I already made. Layout to null, and use .setLocation(x,y).

Comment: ...well look at that...
Thanks! LOL  :)

Comment: There are some problems however: Apparently I can't use the add() function, I get this error:

The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ImageIcon)

I'm not quite sure why I can't use this.  Can you help?

Comment: NeverMind!  I forgot to put the image into a panel and then add the panel, not add the image immediately!

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: No problem, happy programming!

Comment: @Hidde : I tried the `myJPanel.add(image)` and it prompted  - `The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (ImageIcon)` .

Comment: @URL87 It seems that you are not trying to add your image to a `JPanel`, but to a `Container` object. You must have a `JComponent` inherited object to add an `ImageIcon` to it.

Answer (score 3):

Using an ImageIcon with a JLabel is the easiest way. You can actually add this to a level in JFrame's JLayeredPane that is above or below the contentPane depending on your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Develop a custom component  and override `paintComponent()` method to do this. Developing a custom component gives you flexibility for further enhancements. You can add panning, zooming, etc type of capabilities easily this way.

Then just add this component to your `JFrame`.