# How to put an image (jpeg) from your computer on definite coordinates in java Frame?

Tags: java, path, coordinates, jpeg, frame

I have a Frame in java and want to put an image from my computer on a definite coordinate (x,y). How do I do it? And please don't just write a single line, because I want to know what do I need to implement, how do I write the path in and so on, because I'm a beginner. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, and could you please tell me how do I set the coordinates too? Until then I will try if I can make the picture appear on the frame.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806310/display-image-in-java-jframe

Comment: So I did this
String path="D:/Java Workspace/Tetris/src/main/Images/next.jpg";
 ImageIcon icon=createImage("D:/Java Workspace/Tetris/src/main/Images/next.jpg");
private ImageIcon createImage(String path) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
      if (imgURL != null) {
          return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
      } else {
          System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
          return null;
      }
  
 }
But it returns that it couldn't find my file even though it's there. Did I do something wrong? :/

Comment: The `getClass().getResource(path)` will try to find the file inside your project (`relative path`), which means that the path to the file will become something like this `/path/to/your/project/D:/Java Workspace/....`If you are going to use the `absolute path` to the image you can do this `new ImageIcon(path)`